# Running the Python Regression Tests (See Python Documentation 25.5 Development Tools )

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have requested out IT Department to provide a load of Python 3.7.x to replace the obsolete copy of python 2.5 which is provided via the company portal.

This will require the IT department to 'rap' the application to allow it to be downloaded over the company network. I have been requested to test the load.

In order to prove to the IT department that the python 3.7.x load they have produced is successful, I need to run the regression tests that are provided as part of the Python installation.

I have tried running the tests using the commands suggest in the documentation with no success. Has anyone else run these tests and if so how.

Comment: Do you mean https://docs.python.org/3/library/test.html? What's the specific problem you've had?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). It simplifies setting up the build environment for Python and as part of installation builds it from source, along with the included tests. You don't say in your original post whether you're confined to a Windows environment, but since my IT departments are, you may instead want to look at the Windows fork [`pyenv-win`](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win).

With `pyenv` installed, you can build and test a particular Python version like so (using `3.7.4` as an example):

```
$ pyenv install --verbose 3.7.4
```